# First column of join attributes by location on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to join attributes by location using processing (I have many so I need to do them by batch)

```
processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', firstlayer, secondlayer,u'equals',0,0,'',1,layerOutput)
```

The first future are integers then the outputs became all negative numbers.
i.e. 4120034510 becomes -174932786

Could some one help me how to avoid this?  ( may be an easiest way to change first column to string , or better ideas)

Comment: Thank you very much. I now understand that this is  "integer overflow problem".